# Selecting an account for twitter and having it stay selected permanently

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I am building an app with Twitter integrated into it.  I want to be abel to select the account that I want to post as and have that remain permanently selected until I select one of the other accounts.  Now if you select one account it takes to that accounts Feed but if you go back to the Home view and then select Twitter the Feed view is now empty unless I go back to the Home view and select the Accounts button and then go select the account.  I just want to account to be permanently selected until I select another account.

Comment: are you using the Social.framework built into iOS or are you using the Twitter SDK provided by Twitter?

Comment: Social framework.  I believe.  I'm new to this and am learning by doing.  As well as following a tutorial.  But am using the import social